# Extract node from XML like data without extra PHP libs

Tags: php, xml

I am returned the following:

```
<links>
    <image_link>http://img357.imageshack.us/img357/9606/48444016.jpg</image_link>
    <thumb_link>http://img357.imageshack.us/img357/9606/48444016.th.jpg</thumb_link>
    <ad_link>http://img357.imageshack.us/my.php?image=48444016.jpg</ad_link>
    <thumb_exists>yes</thumb_exists>
    <total_raters>0</total_raters>
    <ave_rating>0.0</ave_rating>
    <image_location>img357/9606/48444016.jpg</image_location>
    <thumb_location>img357/9606/48444016.th.jpg</thumb_location>
    <server>img357</server>
    <image_name>48444016.jpg</image_name>
    <done_page>http://img357.imageshack.us/content.php?page=done&amp;l=img357/9606/48444016.jpg</done_page>
    <resolution>800x600</resolution>
    <filesize>38477</filesize>
    <image_class>r</image_class>
</links>
```

I wish to extract the image_link in PHP as simply and as easily as possible. How can I do this?

Assume, I can not make use of any extra libs/plugins for PHP. :)

Thanks all

Comment: Is SimpleXML an "extra" library?

Comment: No, SimpleXML is built-in into PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At Josh's answer, the problem was not escaping the "/" character. So the code Josh submitted would become:

```
$text = 'string_input';
preg_match('/<image_link>([^<]+)<\/image_link>/gi', $text, $regs);
$result = $regs[0];
```

Taking usoban's answer, an example would be:

```
<?php

// Load the file into $content

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content) or die('Error creating a SimpleXML instance');

$imagelink = (string) $xml->image_link; // This is the image link

?>
```

I recommend using SimpleXML because it's very easy and, as usoban said, it's builtin, that means that it doesn't need external libraries in any way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SimpleXML as it is built in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

use regular expressions

```
$text = 'string_input';
preg_match('/<image_link>([^<]+)</image_link>/gi', $text, $regs);
$result = $regs[0];
```

Comment: you need start and end delimiters for preg_match()

Comment: Great Idea! But I get Unknown modifier 'a' for some reason?

Comment: that's because you have an / in <image_link>. It thinks that is the end the regex, the 'i' in image is then a modifier, but it falls over when it gets to 'a' (not a valid modifier). Either escape any forward slashes within the delimiters or use a different delimiter not contained within the pattern (e.g. ~ or |)

Comment: Sorry, I meant you have a / in </image_link>